# In Magento 1.6, changes to login.phtml don’t reflect

Tags: magento

I customized the file app\design\frontend\base\default\template\checkout\onepage\login.phtml to hide the login fields in onepage checkout. It works well in 1.5 version.

When I do the same modifications in 1.6 version, nothing changes in the frontend. I observed that in 1.6 version, onepage.phtml is not using onepage\login.phtml unlike in 1.5. I did the basic checks of file location mistake(base\default and default\default) and cache refresh.

I am having trouble figuring out which login.phtml is being picked up in onepage.phtml in the line getChildHTML(’login’) [to display the login fields in checkout step 1].

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I assume you have no custom theme overwriting this file? Not really a good idea to edit the base files though.

Comment: I have no theme overwriting this file, realised that its picking up from a different location in 1.6 - template/persistent/checkout/onepage/login.phtml

Answer (score 15):

Your problem may be related to the following Thread http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/243571/ about Persistent Shopping Cart.

I encoutered a similar issue because of the template override name:

- before 1.6, my template override was: frontend/default//template/customer/form/login.phtml
- > 1.6: frontend/default//template/persistent/customer/form/login.phtml
  >   Elsewhere you can find the default template path from 1.6 : frontend/base/default/template/persistent/customer/form/login.phtml

For more information about Persistent Shopping Cart, please refer to http://www.magentocommerce.com/blog/comments/persistent-shopping-cart-customer-segmentation-just-getting-better/

Answer (score 5):

a) Do Not ever edit anything in Base, man!

b) Configuration -> Developer, Switch to Website or store or store view scope, turn on Template path hints, Look into your Frontend, you'll See The path!

Comment: Thanks a ton!! It was using app/design/frontend/base/default/template/persistent/checkout/onepage/login.phtml and will stop messing with the Base :)