# Magento custom theme template file not used 1.6

Tags: magento

I have a custom magento template which im trying to tweak and just have a question regarding templates.

Currently the customer login uses the base .phtml file.

So I have created the customer/form/login.phtml file and placed it in my CUSTOM theme folder.

Then in my custom theme folder I went into layouts and and customer.xml. This is where in not sure what I need to do.

I found the following XML code:

```
<customer_account_login translate="label">
    <label>Customer Account Login Form</label>
    <!-- Mage_Customer -->
    <remove name="right"/>
    <remove name="left"/>

    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="customer/form_login" name="customer_form_login" template="customer/form/login.phtml"/>
    </reference>
</customer_account_login>
```

Im not sure what I need to change with this to make it use my custom login form instead of using the base login form.

At first I thought the system would automatically check to see if the file exists in custom and just apply and if it doesnt exist fall back on base template but that didnt seen to work.

Any help would be appreciated. A noob explanation would also be great!

Thanks for reading

Comment: You don't need customer.xml. System will automatically check for .phtml file at your custom dir if your custom theme is set as default in Magento admin, the path to .phtml is correct and your Magento cache is cleared.

Comment: Thats the the thing. The custom template is set and used through the rest of the site, my login.phtml file is in: /app/design/frontend/custom/default/template/customer/form and ive cleared cache multiple times with no joy :( thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Magento seems to use a login file from:
template/persistent/checkout/onepage/login.phtml

In version 1.6 of Magento.

Edited that and the changes appeared as expected. Sorry but i also just found this post

[In Magento 1.6, changes to login.phtml don’t reflect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7538376/in-magento-1-6-changes-to-login-phtml-dont-reflect)

Mine seems to be a dupe (sorry I didnt come across it when searching before) so feel free to close this one :)